# Ligature (combining characters) doesn't show in gVim

Tags: gvim, font

I use JetBrainsMono in my terminal and gVim.

In my terminal, arrows and pipelines become one character visually (`->` and `|>`)

[image]

gVim has the same font but this same behavior doesn't happen.

How can I make this happen in gVim?

Comment: I understand that `->` could be replaced by an arrow but it is unclear to me what should replace `|>` a screenshot  could help.

Comment: image added to the question.

Comment: Which operating system are you using (e.g. Windows 10, Linux)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you refers to a feature called `ligatures`.
Ligature is a special font feature that makes that two characters are merged together on the screen into one that spread over two characters.

For this to work you need a fonts that supports it like (Fira Code but also JetBrains Mono).

On gVim on Windows to unable it you have to set the following option:

```
set renderoptions=type:directx
```

On Linux to unable it you have to set the `guiligatures` option:

```
set guiligatures=!\"#$%&()*+-./:<=>?@[]^_{\|~
```

The font must also support it. I'm using `Fira_Code` or its Nerd equivalent `FiraCode_Nerd_Font`

The text with `Cousine_Nerd_Font_Mono`:

[image: Text with Cousine_Nerd_Font_Mono]

The same text with `FiraCode_Nerd_Font`

[image: Ligature with FiraCode_Nerd_Font]

The same text with `JetBrains_Mono`:

[image: Ligature with JetBrains_Mono]

The same text with `JetBrains_Mono` on Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: Right, I use jetbrainsmono, and `guiligatures` fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-). I understand that you are on Linux with GTK.

Comment: Yes that is right. Linux.